# Computing the Hurst exponent or fractal dimension of fractional Brownian motion

Tags: random, fractals

The Hurst exponent is related to the fractal dimension by noticing that the fractal dimension $D$ is equal to $2-H$, where $d$ is the intrinsic dimension and $H$ is the Hurst exponent, for 1-D fractional Brownian motion.

I can generate an fBm series in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
tlow = 1;
thigh = 1000;
tinc = 1;
hurst = 0.4;    
dataz=RandomFunction[FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[hurst], {tlow, thigh, tinc}, 1];
```

However, using the method [described here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1995/Dec/msg00401.html) to compute the fractal dimension, I am unable to get close to recovering the Hurst exponent used to generate the fBm.

For example:

```
stdev[{x__}] := StandardDeviation[{x}]
stdev[{x_}] := 1
dataf = RotateRight[Mean[R /@ #/stdev /@ #] & /@ (Partition[dataz, 2^#] & /@ Range[10])]
Fit[Log[dataf], {1, x}, x]
```

Is this a numerical error or are there better ways to compute Hurst exponents and fractal dimension in *Mathematica*?

Comment: What is `R[]` ?

Comment: I edited your code for readability. Please undo the edit if you disagree

Comment: I think he uses R as Rescaled Range (The rescaled range is a statistical measure of the variability of a time series...) [Rescaled Range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescaled_range). Also see: [Hust Exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent).  I think I've got a notebook on this I'll try to dig it out of my archive.

Comment: You have some programs in Mathematica to compute fractal dimensions, Hurst coefficient and multi fractals for time series and images in the book Fractal Geography by Andre Dauphine (2013)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Mathematica*'s estimation routines are able to recover the Hurst exponent from the sample:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["mathematica.SE/58539"];
  tlow = 1; thigh = 1000; tinc = 1; hurst = 0.4; 
  dataz = RandomFunction[FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[hurst], {tlow, thigh, tinc}, 1]];

FindProcessParameters[dataz, FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[h]]
```

> {h -> 0.397063}

so the issue must be with your code.

Answer (score 7):

This late answer gives some details of how to calculate a dimension for fractional Brownian motion. The documentation at Help > FractionalBrownianMotionProcess > Basic Examples shows that the variance

```
 Variance[FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma], h][t]]
```

is $t^{2 h} \sigma^2$, which is the same as that on page 84 of The Science of Fractal Images edited by Peitgen and Saupe. They write $\rm{Var}[X(t_2)-X(t_1)]=\sigma^2~Abs[t_2-t_1]^{2~h}$, where the Hurst exponent satisfies $0<h<1$, and the fractal dimension is $D=2-h$.

The strategy is to find the variance $V$ of data points separated by increasingly large time differences $k=t_2-t_1$. The slope and intercept of the best fit line on a log-log plot of $V$ versus $k$ give the Hurst exponent $h$ and volatility $\sigma$, respectively. Thus, $Log[V] = 2 \log[\sigma] + 2 h \log[k]$. The question assumes $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$.

```
Block[{tlow, thigh, tinc, hurst, dataz, u, k, fit},
   SeedRandom["mathematica.SE/58539"];
   tlow = 1;
   thigh = 1000;
   tinc = 1;
   hurst = 0.4;
   dataz = RandomFunction[
              FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[hurst],
              {tlow, thigh, tinc}, 1];
   u = Table[
            {N[Log[k]], Log[Variance[Differences[dataz, 1, k]]]},
            {k, 1, 500}];

   fit = Fit[u, {1, k}, k];

   ListLogLogPlot[u,
      Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {"Log[k] = Log[t2-t1]", "Log[Variance]"},
      PlotLabel -> "Log[V] = " <> ToString[fit],
      Epilog -> {
         Text["\[Sigma] = " <> ToString[E^(fit[[1]]/2)], {0.0, 1.3}],
         Text["h = " <> ToString[fit[[2, 1]]/2], {0.0, 1.0}],
         Thick, Red, 
         Line[{Log[{1, fit /. k -> 1}], Log[{6, fit /. k -> 6}]}]},
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
]
```

[image: log-log plot V vs k]