# What ProcessEstimator Options can I use with FractionalBrownianMotionProcess

Tags: random, distributions

I can generate an fBm process:

```
tlow = 0;
thigh = 1;
len = Sqrt[thigh];
tinc = 0.01;
hurst = 0.4;
DataZ = RandomFunction[
   FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[hurst], {tlow, thigh, tinc}, 1];
dataz = Flatten[DataZ[[2, 1]]];
```

In the following post:

[Computing the Hurst exponent or fractal dimension of fractional Brownian motion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/computing-the-hurst-exponent-or-fractal-dimension-of-fractional-brownian-motion)

it is described that you can use FindProcessParameters to estimate the Hurst exponent:

```
FindProcessParameters[dataz, FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[h]]
```

The documentation says that you can use the ProcessEstimator options... but it does not say which one you can use... I am guessing that such options would be similar to Box counting, Takens estimator, etc.

What are the ProcessEstimator options that can be used with FractionalBrownianMotionProcess?

Answer (score 4):

> The documentation says that you can use the ProcessEstimator options ... but it does not say which one you can use

I take exception to this statement. The documentation for `FindProcessParameters` clearly states two things.

- Option values `Automatic`, `"MaximumLikelihood"`, and `"MethodOfMoments"` can be given generally as values for the option `ProcessEstimator`.
- Certain process functions such as `HiddenMarkovProcess` accept additional option values for `ProcessEstimator`. These are documented under the articles for such processes that do so.

Therefore, if there were addition option values for `ProcessEstimator` accepted by `FractionalBrownianMotionProcess`, they would be found in the article documenting that function. No additional values are mentioned there. Conclusion: there are no such additional option values accepted by `FractionalBrownianMotionProcess` unless the documentation is faulty, which is not inconceivable.